# How can I drag to select multiple gridview items?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this grid view of inkwells for users to select, how could I implement a drag selection feature so the user doesn't have to tap every single square?
The color state is stored into an array and currently on tap updates the array and redraws.

Image below showing the UI

```
 child: InteractiveViewer(
          minScale: 1,
          maxScale: 5,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
            child: GridView.count(
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                crossAxisCount: 32,
                crossAxisSpacing: 3,
                mainAxisSpacing: 3,
                children: List<Widget>.generate(
                    512,
                    (index) => InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          print("tapped " + index.toString());
                          colorArray[index] = pickerColor;

                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        onLongPress: () {
                          colorArray[index] = Colors.white;
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          width: 10,
                          height: 10,
                          color: colorArray[index],
                        )))),
```

[App UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSY5V.png)

Answer (score 0):

what you need is this [drag_select_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/drag_select_grid_view):

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final controller = DragSelectGridViewController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(scheduleRebuild);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.removeListener(scheduleRebuild);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: SelectionAppBar(
        selection: controller.value,
      ),
      body: DragSelectGridView(
        gridController: controller,
        itemCount: 20,
        itemBuilder: (context, index, selected) {
          return SelectableItem(
            index: index,
            selected: selected,
          );
        },
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
          maxCrossAxisExtent: 80,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void scheduleRebuild() => setState(() {});
}
```

Comment: Jim, I did look into using that package but it looks like if you drag two boxes vertically it selects all the boxes in-between (#1 to #4 selects  #2 & #3 as well)

Comment: isn't its purpose meant to be like that?~ horizontal & vertical multiple drag selection